# Parse XLS files to xml or json

Tags: symfony, xls

I get an "xls" response from an webservice. Unfortunately the service only return this format. I would like to parse this file as xml or json. I use the framework symfony. Exist any bundle for handling XLS files, which would you recommend?

Or can i solve this issue with flat PHP?

**Update**

The xls response look like so, here can i show the first few linse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xls:XLS xmlns:xls="http://www.opengis.net/xls" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/xls http://schemas.opengis.net/ols/1.1.0/RouteService.xsd">
  <xls:ResponseHeader xsi:type="xls:ResponseHeaderType" sessionID="unknown"/>
  <xls:Response xsi:type="xls:ResponseType" requestID="unknown" version="1.1" numberOfResponses="1">
    <xls:DetermineRouteResponse xsi:type="xls:DetermineRouteResponseType">
      <xls:RouteSummary>
        <xls:TotalTime>PT22M7S</xls:TotalTime>
        <xls:TotalDistance uom="KM" value="33.7"/>
        <xls:BoundingBox srsName="EPSG:4326">
          <gml:pos>7.8854063 49.9412442</gml:pos>
          <gml:pos>8.2769550 50.0041191</gml:pos>
        </xls:BoundingBox>
      </xls:RouteSummary>
  ......
```

If i try to parse the response with "simplexml_load_string" the function return only the following output.

```
class SimpleXMLElement#1341 (1) {
  public $@attributes =>
  array(1) {
    'version' =>
    string(3) "1.1"
  }
}
```

The function shows me only the version and not the child nodes. How can i access the child nodes?

I try to access the child with this syntax:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
var_dump($xml->children('xls', true)->Response->numberOfResponses);
```

But without any success.

**Solved**

Now i solved my issue.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
echo $xml->children('http://www.opengis.net/xls')->Response->DetermineRouteResponse->RouteSummary->TotalTime;
```

Comment: you can give something like this https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/ or this https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel a shot

Comment: I would like to convert an inputstream (the response for my request). As far as I understand it this libs only work with file handler.